# Cherokee web server on Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: cherokee, ubuntu, web-server

I've been trying to find some decent tutorials on how to set up a recent release of Cherokee webserver on Ubuntu (or equivalent Linux distros) which outline how to setup the webserver, mysql, phpmyadmin and php.

Some already exist, such as http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-cherokee-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-10.04 however, I've found that the Cherokee version used in the tutorial is considerably out of date and the update process has been painful to say the least.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add to your "/etc/apt/sources.list" if you use Ubuntu 10.04

```
#Cherokee Webserver
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cherokee-webserver/ppa/ubuntu lucid main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cherokee-webserver/ppa/ubuntu lucid main
```

Also you will have to add the following GPG

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EBA7BD49
sudo apt-get update
```

Then simply install the Cherokee normal with apt-get. Basically you will need the following packages: cherokee, mysql-server, mysql-client, php5-cgi, php5-mysql, the rest is installed as dependencies.

Before testing you should enable PHP to your vhost like the tutorial you mentioned shows.

Comment: All that is otherwise known as:
`add-apt-repository ppa:cherokee-webserver/ppa`
Though you need the `python-software-properties` package for that command.

Comment: Synchro, you are right, but if the Ubuntu version is below 9.10, your solution does not work.